# How does this for loop know which list to sort through?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the code below which does a bubble sort of the values in the list that is passed through the function.  Can somebody tell me how the for loop knows to go through the list that is being passed through the function?  I thought the for loop should say something like

`for i in values`

but instead it says

`for i in range(0,n-1)`.

```
def bubbleSort(values):
    n = len(values)
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        for j in range(0,n-1):
            if values[j] > values[j +1]:
                values[j],values[j+1] = values[j+1],values[j]


someValues = [22, 10, 3, 84, 5, 12]
bubbleSort(someValues)
print(someValues)
```

Comment: ... then indexes into it, ie `values[i]` and `values[j]`.

Comment: the `0` is implicit in `range`, you could equivalently have `range(n-1)`

Comment: Bubble sort is an in-situ algorithm. Therefore you have to swap elements in the list to be sorted. To this end you need to iterate over the indices of the elements. That's why the loops refer to the index ranges instead of the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `some_list[i]` evaluates to the `i`th value when `some_list` is the name of a Python `list` object instance.

It is valid in Python to write:

```
for elem in some_list:
    ...
```

and expect to operate directly on the values of the list (which, at each iteration, will be denoted by `elem` or whatever loop variable you choose).

It is equally valid to iterate over the range of indices present for the `list` and access the `list` within the loop at points where the appropriate element is desired:

```
for i in range(0, len(some_list)-1):
    elem = some_list[i]
    ...
```

and you can even iterate while keeping track of *both* the current index into the array *and* the element at that position, by using the `enumerate` function:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(some_list):
    some_list[i] == elem #True, unless you've mutated the list (don't!)
    ...
```